# Access a class of current package

Tags: python

I'm trying to access a class which is defined in the same package from where I try to access it, but in a different file. This class is already imported in the package's `__init__.py`.

I know that I can do this to get a reference to the current package, and from that reference I can get the class which is imported in `__init__.py` as an attribute. But is there no shorter way of doing that?

```
import importlib

current_package = importlib.import_module('.'.join(__name__.split('.')[:-1]))

# getting the class I want
cls = getattr(current_package, myclass)
```

I'd think that's a common action, so I'm surprised to not find a shortcut for doing it.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages?

Comment: Yes, the class name I import is dynamic.

Comment: ...but it will always be `myclass`? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thx, i fixed the example to illustrate that the class name i need is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer myself. There is a variable `__package__` which I can use to avoid having to generate the package name:

```
import importlib

current_package = importlib.import_module(__package__)

# getting the class I want
cls = getattr(current_package, myclass)
```